# How to return newest record in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to return the most recent record in an array according to message_date. How would i go about this? I have this piece of code returning all and have tried using last etc. but I'm not too sure what i'm doing.

```
contact_messages_threads(@customer.id).each do |openmessagethread|
  - @messagelast = openmessagethread.message_date
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. Is `contact_messages_threads(@customer.id)` or `openmessagethread` the array you want to find the newest record in?

Comment: @EgonWilzer contact_messages_threads is the method and I assume openmessagethread is the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get it like this if `contact_messages_threads(@customer.id)` returns the array:

```
@messagelast = contact_messages_threads(@customer.id).max_by(&:message_date)
```

Comment: For what? So `openmessagethread` is not the array? Can  you try `@messagelast = contact_messages_threads(@customer.id).max_by(&:message_date)` ?

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Really confused matters. Thanks for clarifying. I thought contact_messages_threads was a method as I have defined it elsewhere.